# flagging the first time a record based on parameter appears in r dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, head

I have a dataframe `df` that contains several columns.

The dataframe is already sorted by Contact ID `C_ID`. A `C_ID` can appear multiple times in the dataframe. I want to put an "X" in the column `MainRecord` the first time the `C_ID` appears so that the result would be as follows:

```
C_ID  Name  MainRecord
1     JM    X
1     JM  
1     JM  
2     DM    X
3     TY    X
3     TY
```

I think my solution would need to reference the `head` function: `df[,head(1)]`

Comment: Here are some other ways (though you'll still have to map 0/1 to blank/X if you still want to do that): https://stackoverflow.com/q/26265732/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'C_ID', 'Name', and create the 'MainRecord' with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(C_ID, Name) %>%
  mutate(MainRecord = case_when(row_number()==1 ~ "X", TRUE ~ ""))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   C_ID, Name [3]
#   C_ID Name  MainRecord
#  <int> <chr> <chr>     
#1     1 JM    X         
#2     1 JM    ""        
#3     1 JM    ""        
#4     2 DM    X         
#5     3 TY    X         
#6     3 TY    ""
```

---

Or another option is `ifelse`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(C_ID, Name) %>% 
   mutate(MainRecord = ifelse(row_number()==1, "X", ""))
```

---

Or use indexing

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(C_ID, Name) %>% 
   mutate(MainRecord = c("", "X")[(row_number()==1) + 1])
```

---

Or with `data.table`, get the row index with `.I` and assign (`:=`) the 'X' value that corresponds to the rows

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[seq_len(.N) == 1], .(C_ID, Name)]$V1
df1[i1, MainRecord := "X"]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
i1 <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(C_ID), C_ID, Name, FUN = seq_along)==1)
df1$MainRecord[i1] <- "X"
```

Comment: A one-line version of the data.table one: `df1[!duplicated(df1, by=c("C_ID", "Name")), MainRecord := "X"]` since duplicated.data.table has a by= arg.